# Creating a setup.exe in InstallShield in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, installation, windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2010

Please tell me whether it is possible to create a file named setup.exe. I want to have the end user to a single file installer. At this point, I click 'build' and the output like this:[image: output files]

I would like to output was a setup.exe. If it is not possible, then the setup.exe file.msi

basic msi | 2010 premier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you just use the release wizard:

[Release Wizard](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield12helplib/IHelpReleaseWizIDERef.htm)

When you get to the Media Type dialog select "Network Image" , on the Release Configuration dialog select "Compress All Files" and on the Setup Laucncher Dialog select "Create Installation Launcher (Setup.exe)"