# Create simple setup.exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have found loads of refernces to creating a simple setup.exe file in VS by doing the new project - setup wizzard but there is only Enable InstallShield Limited Edition.

I can't install the following for VS 2015, it thinks VS is not installed:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d

Any advise?  I don't want all of the folders and files that come with publishing my application, only setup.exe

Thanks

Comment: Publish your app following [these instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9581929/62576).

Comment: Hey thanks, I was trying to find another solution as InstallSheild does not support Visual Studio 2015 but I couldn't find anything so I am having to uninstall it and install Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: The other option is to use something outside VS, such as [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) (which is free).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No other option available for my needs.

Had to uninstall VS 2015 and install VS 2013 to be able to use InstallSheild.

Follow these instructions provided by @Ken White

[Creating a setup.exe in InstallShield in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581929/creating-a-setup-exe-in-installshield-in-visual-studio)